# Installed native JAI, getting black lines

Tags: java, jai

When I install native JAI I get black lines in my scaled images. Does anyone know how to avoid this?

```
                    ParameterBlockJAI pb = new ParameterBlockJAI("scale");
                    pb.addSource(image);
                    pb.setParameter("xScale", (float) from.getScale());
                    pb.setParameter("yScale", (float) from.getScale());
                    pb.setParameter("xTrans", 0.0F);
                    pb.setParameter("yTrans", 0.0F);
                    pb.setParameter("interpolation", new InterpolationNearest());
                    resultingImage = JAI.create("scale", SubsampleAverageDescriptor.create(resultingImage, from.getScale(), from.getScale(), new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY)), null);
```

[image: example image with black lines]

Answer (score 0):

I updated native JAI to the latest daily build and the problem went away. Downloaded from [daily builds](https://jai.dev.java.net/binary-builds.html#Daily_builds)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it’s one of the bugs [#82](https://jai-core.dev.java.net/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=82) or #120?